# How to Validate if the input Text in ComboBox was on the list?

Tags: c#, combobox

How to assure if the inputted text in the ComboBox was on the list?

Comment: What do you mean? `combobox1.IndexOf(`? or `list.IndexOf(combobox.Text`

Comment: what i mean is how can i assured that the inputted text by the user before he leave the comboBox was on the list.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have, might make it easy to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @jersoft if this is winform project, tag it as winform

Comment: you have a list and you to check that if inputted value exist in list alert you. am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `Leave` event which will check the value when focus is lost on the `ComboBox`

```
    private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
        {
            throw new EndOfWorldException();
        }
    }
```

or use the `TextUpdated` event to set the text color red if the item does not exist when the user enters the text

```
    private void comboBox1_TextUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.ForeColor = comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text)
            ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
    }
```